# How to combine dataframes by columns?

Tags: r, cbind

I have two dataframes and they look like:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(19, 79, 34),
  B = c(21, 21, 14),
  C = c(17, 14, 57)
)
row.names(df) <- c("2016-10-31",    "2016-09-30",   "2016-08-31")
df
            A  B  C
2016-10-31 19 21 17
2016-09-30 79 21 14
2016-08-31 34 14 57

df2 <- data.frame(
  A_Return = c(0.1, 0.9,    0.4),
  B_Return = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4),
  C_Return = c(0.7, 0.4, 0.7)
)
row.names(df2) <- c("2016-10-31",   "2016-09-30",   "2016-08-31")
df2
           A_Return B_Return C_Return
2016-10-31      0.1      0.1      0.7
2016-09-30      0.9      0.2      0.4
2016-08-31      0.4      0.4      0.7
```

The dataframes have identical row names, and I know `cbind` or `merge` can combine them together. But I want the columns in the following order:

```
            A  A_Return  B  B_Return  C  C_Return
2016-10-31 19      0.1  21       0.1 17       0.7
2016-09-30 79      0.9  21       0.2 14       0.4
2016-08-31 34      0.4  14       0.4 57       0.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `merge` by `row.names`

```
dfN <- merge(df, df2, by = "row.names")
row.names(dfN) <- dfN$Row.names
dfN1 <- dfN[-1][order(colnames(dfN)[-1])]
```

Comment: That will just merge two dataframes. What I am looking for is to have `A_Return` next to `A` and `B_Return` next to `b` etc.

Comment: @T-T  Updated the post